# Explain the use of full-stop/period/point in a paragraph

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I use COBOL in my business and I originally learned at a a site using `perform - thru ...`.

Now I have changed jobs and the local programming standards are different, so I need to get used to PERFORM without THRU.

I also have a doubt about the use of the full-stop/period/point in a paragraph.

You can use the period to end sentences within a paragraph. I say this because I read in places that the *paragraph* ends with the first point, and elsewhere I see full-stop/period/point used differently to that.

I wrote two structures below which I understand should be equal. Is that so?

Structure A:

```
       PERFORM 100-WRITING.
       PERFORM 200-FINISH.



100-WRITING.
*-----------
   DISPLAY "HI MY NAME IS FELIPE".
   DISPLAY "THE WORLD IS GREAT".
   DISPLAY "I DONT SPEAK ENGLISH".
200-FINISH.
*----------
   DISPLAY "BYE BYE BABY".
   DISPLAY "ESTO ES TODO".
```

Structure B:

```
       PERFORM 100-WRITING.
       PERFORM 200-FINISH.



100-WRITING.
*-----------
   DISPLAY "HI MY NAME IS FELIPE"
   DISPLAY "THE WORLD IS GREAT"
   DISPLAY "I DONT SPEAK ENGLISH".
200-FINISH.
*----------
   DISPLAY "BYE BYE BABY"
   DISPLAY "ESTO ES TODO".
```

Comment: Should be the same. `PERFORM THROUGH` is evil - it produces layout-dependent code.

Comment: @Magoo: PERFORM 1000-CODE THRU 1000-EXIT is not evil.  It's just a different COBOL style.

Comment: "Evil" might be a strong word for it, but code styles that actively promote the shooting of oneself in the foot should be discouraged in favor of those that do not.  We could just write everything in bare-metal machine language, after all, that is just another code style...

Comment: With Unisys 2200 COBOL and DMS database, ON ERROR GO TO was the preferred error handling method, so encapsulating database access into PERFORM ... THRU ... paragraph blocks was essential, for sanity's sake.

Comment: @Kennah Use of SECTIONs would obviate the need for PERFORM ... THRU ... in that type of case. SECTIONs are not a perfect answer, because the uknowing can insert a paragraph and not realise that that attaches it to the previous SECTION (in the same was as a paragraph can be unwittingly included in a THRU-range), but with SECTIONs there's less "stuff" (just `PERFORM section-name`, which is identical to the `PERFORM paragraph-name`). SECTIONs can provide some measure of protection against a copy/paste GO TO with no change of name (make all the exit-names the same).

Comment: For one of my sinful past programming lives, we did EVERYTHING in Sections. I concluded that the shop was eyeball deep in Jackhole programmers who didn't know IS NULL from = "NULL". As such, at a time before I arrived there, some "genius" decreed that THOU SHALT ALWAYS USE THINE SECTIONS. This eliminated the problem of feral GO TO statements that ventured outside of the PERFORM ... THRU ... block. One could also make a global change from GO TO [A-Za-z0-9-]+ to EXIT SECTION.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, the code you show is equivalent.

A paragraph or a SECTION *must* end with a full-stop/period/point. This means that the last thing (other than a comment or a blank line) in a paragraph or a SECTION must be a full-stop/period/point.

This does not mean that a full-stop/period/point *actually ends* a paragraph or SECTION. You are correct, a full-stop/period/point in a paragraph ends a sentence. A paragraph or SECTION must contain sentences only. Therefore a paragraph or SECTION must end with a full-stop/period/point because a sentence must end with one.

```
   PERFORM 100-WRITING
   PERFORM 200-FINISH
   .

100-WRITING.
*-----------
   DISPLAY "HI MY NAME IS FELIPE"
   DISPLAY "THE WORLD IS GREAT"
   DISPLAY "I DONT SPEAK ENGLISH"
   .
200-FINISH.
*----------
   DISPLAY "BYE BYE BABY"
   DISPLAY "ESTO ES TODO"
   .
```

Since the 1985 COBOL standard, sentences are no longer really important in COBOL in the `PROCEDURE DIVISION`, so it is only extra work if they are made important by the coder.

I find it much more convenient to re-write like the above. Don't attach the full-stop/period/point to *anything*. Just have it on in a line of its own. Then it means you can move around any of the lines in a paragraph/SECTION without worrying about whether the full-stop/period/point is in the correct place, because it is not actually attached to anything, so it never gets move around until you need it for the next paragraph/SECTION.

However, your site coding standards may not allow you to do this. You could always attempt to get them changed for the better :-)